# Find IPs in a text file and convert them to URL

Tags: php, html, sed, awk

OK this should be realy simple but my head is about to explode.
I have a html file, it has anywhere from 10-15 different IP addresses.

I need a way to convert the IP addresses to HTML links within the file. I can either run a script against the file or I can add code to the HTML file. Im not too concerned with how I get it done I just need to get it done :)

Example:

```
192.168.0.50 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod                             tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
192.168.0.51 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea    
192.168.0.52 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I need to fine each address 192.168.0.XXX and replace it with `<a href="http://192.168.0.XXX">192.168.0.XXX</a>`

Thank you

Comment: include what you've tried and it might not get closed

Comment: also, the function you need is `preg_replace()`

Comment: look at why your last question was closed, that's what is going to happen here. you cant just ask for code

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = preg_replace('/([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})/', '<a href="http://$1">$1</a>', $s);
```

Or for just that range of IPs use:

```
'/(192\.168\.0\.[\d]{1,3})/'
```

Comment: +1 Even though, there is one issue in you code - it doesn't validate IP address! So 492.168.0.50 would also be converted! Fix it and it will answer the question, I think!

Comment: `/(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})/` why not just that regex? But yeah, I agree it should validate as well.